# Testing an android app generating specific xml junit file

Tags: android, junit, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I'm using Android Studio and the gradle plugin to build apps from the command line.

Now, suppose I want to run tests on my connected devices, I run:

```
  ./gradlew app:connectedCheck
```

and it will output a junit report XML file on:

```
./app/build/outputs/androidTest-results/connected/flavors/latest/TEST-Galaxy Nexus - 4.3-app-Latest.xml
```

This is almost what I want. Just that I would like to specify for example this test output file. For example, I would like to output it to $HOME/junit.xml. And I would like to specify this $HOME/junit.xml from the command line.

How do I do this?

Comment: What you can do is create a task that depends on connectedCheck task and move after all xml files generated.

Answer (score 2):

You can specify the output directory for test reports using

```
    android {

    testOptions {
        reportDir = "$project.buildDir/foo/report"
    }
}
```

http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Test-reports